# Time from X not working properly in momentjs

Tags: momentjs

Suppose i give startdate as 2016-11-30 and enddate as 2017-11-06 then i get 11 months when using moment's from method

```
var start = moment("2016-11-30");
var end = moment("2017-11-06");
start.from(end, true);

 o/p:   "11 months"
```

However if i give start date as "2016-11-21" with same end date then i am getting "a year"

```
var start = moment("2016-11-21");
start.from(end, true);

o/p:   "a year"
```

Is this a bug in moment.js or some thing wrong in my calculation

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/

Comment: I always get `a year`, which moment version are you using?

Comment: Thank you @VincenzoC the project in which i was working had older version ie., version : 2.1.0, changing to latest version resolved the isue